# Filling potholes in my dirt driveway

Tags: repair, driveway, rain, slope

My driveway (see picture) has developed potholes that are so deep that the high parts can hit the bottom of the car!

My driveway is a dirt driveway with crushed blacktop on top. Also, it is **very steep** in the section that has potholes. So I think that if I were to just fill the potholes with dirt, the next rain would wash them right out.

Any suggestions on the right approach to fix this problem?

My question is similar to [this one](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/43874/stabilizing-a-gravel-driveway-with-massive-holes-and-steep-inclination), but my driveway is already shaped correctly to guide the rain water. I would like to figure out how to fill the potholes with dirt and at the same time get the dirt to adhere to the bottom of the pothole.

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: ¾" crushed stone is a favorite for driveway material. It packs good and stays put.

Comment: Would I be able to put dirt over it and make it stay there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick with the crushed rock.  In the deeper holes you could start with 1-1/4"minus.  As you get closer to the surface you go smaller and smaller.  forget the dirt.  you are wasting your time.